# Different IP for each tab Firefox

Tags: firefox, ip

I know there are some extensions that allow us to have different sessions in the same Browser, however they all are connected through the same IP address, I need to know if there is a way to change the IP in each tab, I bought a proxy in ProxyBonanza but I am just able to set it to the whole browser.

Let me know if you have any idea about my problem.

Comment: I would be surprised if this is possible with Firefox since all tabs run in the same process (this is changing - already changed in development versions I think?). With Chrome each tab is a different process, so probably a better chance that you could make it work with that.

Comment: it might (dunno) be possible by using a vpn service via add-on such as anonymox...

Comment: Chrome would be nice too

Comment: I think with Anonymox (available for Firefox and Chrome) you can set it to work with some tabs and not others, so that gives you two ips anyway (your real one and the anonymox-provided one). Of course you put yourself in the hands of the anonymox people and I have no idea who they are...

Comment: I just check it but since it gives two IPs it doesn't work for me, I need lots more :s thank you anyway